# Python2 and Python3: __init__ and __new__

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, init, super

I have read other questions which explain the difference between `__init__` and `__new__` but I just do not understand why in the following code with python 2 out:

```
init
```

and Python3:

```
new
init
```

The sample code:

```
class ExampleClass():
    def __new__(cls):
        print ("new")
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        print ("init")

example = ExampleClass()
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong for the python2 example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use `__new__` in Python 2.x, the class should be [new-style class](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/) (class derived from `object`).

And call to [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) is different from that of Python 3.x.

```
class ExampleClass(object):  # <---
    def __new__(cls):
        print("new")
        return super(ExampleClass, cls).__new__(cls)  # <---

    def __init__(self):
        print("init")
```